# Angular 5 - Ng-x spinner not showing when used in function

Tags: angular, angular5, spinner

I am not sure if someone experiences this.
Whenever I'm trying to use ngx-spinner in a function its not working.
But when I put it inside the subscribed callback, it's working.

Outside the authservice. This is not showing the spinner.

```
login() {
  this._spinner.show(); //spinner call
  this._authService.login(this.user).subscribe(
    data => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("account", JSON.stringify(data[0].data));
      sessionStorage.setItem("token", data[0].data.access_token);
      setInterval(() => {
        this._router.navigate(['home']);
      }, 2000);
    },
    error => {
    }
  )
 this._spinner.hide();
}
```

Inside authservice. This is working

```
login() {
  this._authService.login(this.user).subscribe(
    data => {
      this._spinner.show(); //spinner call
      sessionStorage.setItem("account", JSON.stringify(data[0].data));
      sessionStorage.setItem("token", data[0].data.access_token);
      setInterval(() => {
        this._router.navigate(['home']);
      }, 2000);
    },
    error => {
    }
  )
 this._spinner.hide();
}
```

I've imported all the necessary library, but for some reason, it's not working when it is outside of the authservice.

Answer (score 1):

```
login() {
  this._spinner.show(); //spinner call
  this._authService.login(this.user).subscribe(
    data => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("account", JSON.stringify(data[0].data));
      sessionStorage.setItem("token", data[0].data.access_token);
      setInterval(() => {
        this._router.navigate(['home']);
      }, 2000);
 this._spinner.hide();
    },
    error => {
 this._spinner.hide();
    }
  )

}
```