# ngx-spinner is not working outside of subscribe

Tags: angular6

Below is the code I tried to execute in ngOnInit().

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show('full_settings');
    this.settings_api.get_all_settings().subscribe(response => {    
        console.log(response);
    }, error => {
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```

While executing this code spinner is not showing. There is no any console error too. So I tried to place spinner.show() inside the subscribe. That's working fine.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.settings_api.get_all_settings().subscribe(response => {    
        this.spinner.show('full_settings');
        console.log(response);
    }, error => {
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```

I want it to work from outside of subscribe. I found the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531840/angular-5-ng-x-spinner-not-showing-when-used-in-function), but the solution said in there is not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below code. I think a little timeout will fix the issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => { this.spinner.show('full_settings'); }, 30);
    this.settings_api.get_all_settings().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }, error => {
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```

Comment: its working like a charm. That's an easy fix. Thank you.

Comment: Will it work if the subscribe method will take 3 seconds to resolve the data?